# How would I make an event option change after an event is used on RPG MAKER VX ACE?

Tags: rpg, rpg-maker-vx

I am trying to make my first RPG, and I am trying to make someone say something talking to someone once, but then when talking them to a second time, they something else.

How would I do that?

Comment: Nothing, seeing that I know nothing about variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/59472/14) for a bit of information on how you can use switches and variables.

To achieve this, you are also going to use a switch. But you can be a bit more efficient (and not waste global switch/variable space) by using a local one for it.

It should be on the right pane of the event manager (I think they are labeled A, B, C, D). Basically you would set it to true after you've spoken to the person, then on another page check to see if it was set and output different dialog if it was.